# Where are the logs for my user-data script? cloud-init

Tags: cloud-init

If I paste a shell script into the user-data box when starting the standard Ubuntu AMI on EC2, I'm using cloud-init, am I not? My question is where does it log the output of such a script? Do I have to do something to turn logging on? I can't find logs for it anywhere.

Ubuntu-raring-13.04-amd64-server-20130423 (ami-c30360aa)

Thanks!

Comment: This question is a second attempt after trying the [same question on stack-overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691867/where-to-find-logs-for-a-cloudinit-user-data-script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Output of your program is available on the console log.  You can get that either from the aws console, or by calling the GetConsoleOutput via the api (or with a tool such as euca-get-console-output or ec2-get-console-output).

Additionally, you can tell cloud-init to log the output of those commands by providing user-data that tells it to.

```
#cloud-config
output: {all: '| tee -a /var/log/cloud-init-output.log'}
```

You can provide multi-part input to give both '#!' scripts and cloud-config as shown above.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit for an example of how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You will found all log in the following folder :

```
/var/log/installer/
```

You can find there after installation too.
Interesting file :

```
/var/log/installer/installer-journal.txt
/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data
/var/log/installer/curtin-install.log
```

Hop it's help